# network communication encryption in java

Tags: java, security, encryption, networking

A friend and me are working on a Java Game with a client/server - architecture.
It is working well, but i ran into a problem.
We use TCP Sockets for networking between server and client.
Our network protocol isnt encrypted and can just be read by anone who bothers to watch the stream.

We thought about how we could apply some kind of cryptography to it to hide login information and prevent people to write their own clients. But basic things like adding/substracting bytes seems pretty easy to figure out.

What are the usual methods used to encrypt network communication for games( or at least game login information )? And having written the server and client in java, are there any useful java libraries?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use public-key encryption (RSA for example) and implement something like the [SSL Handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake_in_detail), or of course use SSL - [here you can see an example](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=32388).

Here's a simplified sequence:

- the server sends his public RSA key to the client
- the client generates a symmetric key (using AES for example)
- the client encrypts the symmetric key with the server's public key and sends it to the server
- the server decrypts the received symmetric key

Now both the client and the server have a key which no one eavesdropping can know. Then use that key to encrypt all data.

Comment: Works, but anyone who has a valid client and a valid login can still reverse engineer the protocol and thus create a custom client...

Comment: JSSE seems to be what i was looking for and ill just have to change the sockettypes and create the keys. 
for the reverse engineerign part, that isnt a problem in this project since it wont be anything big and i dont think anyone will waste their time re-ing this one and was thought as a learning experience.
and if it happens i guess ill have to roll out a update to get rid of a custom client till someone caught up.
Thx for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

**SSL**(Secure Sockets Layer) is popular to handle this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the javax.crypto library or bouncyCastle.

Both provide cryptographic primitives, also for encryption. Depending on how secure you want to have it, you can use symmetric or assymetric crypto. However, also think about key management in advance. Where do you store your private/shared key.

If it is a client-server, the best way would be to use assymetric crypto (i.e. RSA, Elliptic Curve) and give every user a certificate signed with the key of the server (note, this is TLS (formerly called SSL)). This way you can check if the user logging on is authentic. However, you dont prevent custom clients since the user has to have everyone can just copy the certificate.

In practice, it is quite hard to prevent custom clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ciphers](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/security/ch13_06.htm). Some more examples [here](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-classes-2503.html) and [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/security/ch13_05.htm)